# /clang:-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening nothing I do seem to matter and the compiler shows no errors. I just keep getting the same error about the linker command and I can't seem to find anything online that fixes my problem. Im am using xcode 10.

Error

```
/clang:-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is my header file with the functions

```
#ifndef SINGLELINK_H
#define SINGLELINK_H

#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
using std::ostream; using std::cout; using std::endl;

template <typename T>
struct Node{
public:
    Node *next_;
    T data_;

    Node() : data_( T() ), next_(nullptr) {};
    Node(T d) : data_(d), next_(nullptr) {};
};

template <typename T>
class SingleLink{
private:
    Node<T> *head_;
    Node<T> *tail_;

public:
    SingleLink()=default;
    SingleLink(T dat){
        Node<T>* n = new Node<T>(dat);
        head_ = n;
        tail_ = n;
    }
    void append_back(T dat){
        Node<T>* n = new Node<T>(dat);
        if (tail_ != nullptr){
            tail_->next_ = n;
            tail_ = n;
        }
        else {
            head_=n;
            tail_=n;
        }
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, SingleLink<T>& s){
        std::ostringstream oss;
        Node<T> *ptr;
        for(ptr = s.head_; ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr->next_)
            oss << ptr << ",";
        std::string str = oss.str();
        out << str.substr(0,str.size()-1);
        return out;
    };
    //bool del(T val);
   // Node<T>& SingleLink<T>::operator[](size_t index);

    // Rule of three stuff, if you get time. Look at 21.2
    ~SingleLink();
    SingleLink(const SingleLink &);
    SingleLink& operator=(SingleLink);

};

// YOUR STUFF HERE





#endif
```

And my main file

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::ostream;
#include<string>
using std::string;

#include "lab13_singlelink.h"

int main () {
    SingleLink<string> sl;
    sl.append_back("beds");
    //sl.append_front("tables");
   // sl.append_back("chairs");
    cout << sl << endl;
    //Node<string> *n = sl.find("tables");
    /*if (n != nullptr){
        sl.insert_after("rugs", n);
        cout << sl << endl << endl;
    }*/

    /*SingleLink<string> s2(sl);
    s2.append_back("lamps");
    s2.append_front("sofas");
    cout << sl << endl << endl;
    cout << s2 << endl << endl;
    sl = s2;
    sl.append_back("cabinets");
    cout << sl << endl << endl;
    cout << s2 << endl << endl;*/

}
```

Comment: Please include the error message from the linker into your question.

Comment: I'd guess it's complaining about the missing implementation of `~SingleLink();`

Comment: Well now I feel like a idiot thanks